# Ubuntu 14.04 freezes after login if additional display is connected to my laptop

Tags: 14.04, apt, freeze, external-monitor

Ubuntu freezes after login if I have connected additional display to my laptop. Otherwise, I can normally boot without additional display. It also works fine if I connect monitor after I'm already in desktop mode. 
I already tried these but it didn't worked:

```
$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

and

```
$ sudo su
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
$ apt-get install unity
$ reboot
```

Thanks.