# 14.04 hangs after login, no desktop

Tags: 14.04, login, login-screen

Mouse is still responsive,  guest account can login and I can still login to my account through tty1. I've tried reinstalling ubuntu-desktop but it didn't change anything.

I'm not sure what other context I can provide, but I'll will endeavour to provide whatever is asked for.

Comment: After finding http://askubuntu.com/questions/769217/ubuntu-14-04-freezes-after-login-if-additional-display-is-connected-to-my-laptop I disconnected my second display too find that I can login successfully and then connect my display after logging in. I'm still open to debugging this with someone more knowledgeable.